# parsing sentence into words and punctuations mark

Tags: java, string, split

I need to parse class `Sentence` into word and punctuation (whitespace is considered as a punctuation mark), then add all of it into general `ArrayList<Sentence>`.

An example sentence:

> A man, a plan, a canal — Panama!
>   A => word
>   whitespase  => punctuation
>   man         => word
>   , + space   => punctuation
>   a           => word
>   [...]

I tried to read this whole sentence one character at a time and collect the same and create new word or new `Punctuation` from this collection.

Here's my code:

```
public class Sentence {

    private String sentence;
    private ArrayList<Word> words;
    private ArrayList<Punctuation> punctuations;

    /**
     * Constructs a sentence.
     * @param aText a string containing all characters of the sentence
     */
    public Sentence(String aText) {
        sentence = aText;

        int i = 0;
        while (Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(i))) {  // I stuck here
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Maybe other approaches are much better? Any suggestions?

***How to solve this problem?***

Comment: You're stuck even before you began. You came here too early in your process.  Assume that you have all the means and create a pseudo-code.  Then you can start thinking about Java language features / standard classes / APIs that you can use to build such functionality.  If at that stage you have particular problems, come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: try this, though i'm not sure how punctuatuon gets tagged http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to define what you consider to be punctuation and move that into the punctuation list.

Anything else you can just append to a string buffer letter by letter. Once you come to a character that is punctuation you store the previous "word" and the punctuation mark.

Use a StringBuffer to append your letters to to build up each "word".

If you can do it might be preferable to use a for loop instead. You can then check if you have a punctuation mark (adding the previous word, adding the punctuation then clearing out your StringBuffer) or adding your "letter" to your StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//before using sentence check if its null and not empty
char tempChar = sentence.charAt(0);
while (tempChar != '\n') {  
    if(tempChar == ' ' || tempChar == '+' || /* and so on */){
        //Add to punctuations
    }else if(Character.isLetter(tempChar)){

        //save the tempChar and continue (with incremental i )till you get a punctuation
        //Add to characters saved in words array
    }

    i++;
}
```

This is not a correct answer but this is what I can think of at 2:30am in the night lol